# Как указать имя отправителя сообщения в переменную (discord.py)

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу сделать чтобы бот при прописывании команды получал приватный текстовый канал, который может видеть только он. Для этого мне надо узнать его `id` я попробовал многое в том числе

```
#author = ctx.message.author
id = {author.mention}
```

В интернете тоже ничего не нашёл

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
bot.remove_command( 'help' )
token = 'Токен бота'

@bot.command()
async def приват(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    guild.ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ОТПРАВИТЕЛЬ: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
    await guild.create_text_channel("Приватный-канал", overwrites=overwrites)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot started...")
bot.run(token)
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все контекстные объекты можно достать из `ctx`, который контекстом и является.

Ключом в словаре "перезаписей" может быть как пользователь, так и роль, и они не обязательно должны быть аттрибутами сервера (`Guild`).

```py
@bot.command()
async def приват(ctx):
    overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("Приватный-канал", overwrites=overwrites)
```